# Can wget be used to download the resource at the URL?

Tags: wget

Why can't I  download a file with wget:

```
$ wget http://www.abook.cn/pdf/H-0552.0101.pdf
--2020-07-26 09:46:28--  http://www.abook.cn/pdf/H-0552.0101.pdf
Resolving www.abook.cn (www.abook.cn)... 103.59.150.133
Connecting to www.abook.cn (www.abook.cn)|103.59.150.133|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

--2020-07-26 09:48:40--  (try: 2)  http://www.abook.cn/pdf/H-0552.0101.pdf
Connecting to www.abook.cn (www.abook.cn)|103.59.150.133|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

--2020-07-26 09:50:52--  (try: 3)  http://www.abook.cn/pdf/H-0552.0101.pdf
Connecting to www.abook.cn (www.abook.cn)|103.59.150.133|:80...
```

but I can save the resource at the URL with [the wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20200726034218/http://www.abook.cn/pdf/H-0552.0101.pdf)?

Can wget be used to download the resource at the URL, like the wayback machine does? If not, what some other tools can?

Comment: wget on the wayback machine URL got me an HTML file, but you can click on the download button of the PDF to get the PDF file.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the link you provided "The Wayback Machine" was of a HTML page, you want to `wget https://web.archive.org/web/20200726034218if_/http://www.abook.cn/pdf/H-0552.0101.pdf`

This can be found by looking at the page source, and finding the iframe that loads the PDF, `<iframe id="playback" src=`

I would personally recommend however you store this file on your own web server, CDN etc - then pull it from there.

Comment: I have clarified my question.

Comment: @Newbie Well, to answer that question - you'd need to ask them (the owners of the website), I am able to `wget http://www.abook.cn/pdf/H-0552.0101.pdf` (same IP). It's possible you're being blocked, maybe by a web application firewall (waf)...

I'd try from a different location (_different public ip_), and you can also try adjusting your `wget` user agent (however I suspect that's not an issue, since I have no issue as mentioned).